# Macro to set Header in Excel works when stepping through it, but not when running full macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have created the macro below to format a worksheet, add headers based on user input boxes then export the worksheet to a pdf.  The macro works fine when I step through it, but when I run the full macro, it picks up the header values that were input during the previous run.  Does anyone have any ideas as to why this might be?

```
Private Sub pFormatPrint()
    Dim Rep As String
    Dim Period As String
    Dim Fname As String
        
    Rep = InputBox("Please input REP", "REP")                                               'Header 1
    Period = InputBox("Please input Reporting Period", "Commission Reporting Period")       'Header 2
    Fname = InputBox("Please input last day of report period as YYYY.MM.DD", "File Name")   'to be used in pdf file name
    
    Sheets("Query").Select
    
    'set header based upon variables defined from user input box
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
            With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
                .CenterHeader = _
                "&""Georgia,Bold""OJM Group, LLC" & Chr(10) & Rep & "" & "Commissions" & Chr(10) & Period
                .FitToPagesWide = 1
                .FitToPagesTall = 10
            End With
        
    'format report
     ActiveSheet.ListObjects("pia_commissions").ListColumns(5).Range.Select
     Selection.ColumnWidth = 13
        With Selection
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
            .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
            .WrapText = True
        End With
     ActiveSheet.ListObjects("pia_commissions").ListColumns(6).Range.Select
     Selection.ColumnWidth = 13
        With Selection
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
            .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
            .WrapText = True
        End With
     ActiveSheet.ListObjects("pia_commissions").ListColumns(7).Range.Select
     Selection.ColumnWidth = 13
        With Selection
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
            .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
            .WrapText = True
        End With
    
     'Export report to PDF
     ActiveSheet.ListObjects("pia_commissions").Range.Select
     Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="Comm " & Rep & Fname
     
    Application.PrintCommunication = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I am assuming you are referring to the `.CenterHeader` ? Also a must read for you [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Yes, I am referring to the .CenterHeader.  I have to run the macro twice for it to pick up the new data from the Input Box, but if I step through the macro using F8 it picks it up the first time.  Also, thank you for the link to learning how to avoid "Select"